# "Expected "payload" to be a plain object" when signing a jwt token

Tags: node.js, jwt, hapi

This is the error

```
apis_1      | Error: Expected "payload" to be a plain object.
apis_1      |     at validate (/lens-apis/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:40:11)
apis_1      |     at validatePayload (/lens-apis/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:62:10)
apis_1      |     at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/lens-apis/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:114:7)
apis_1      |     at /lens-apis/dist/org/signup/signup.route.js:115:37
apis_1      |     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
apis_1      |     at fulfilled (/lens-apis/dist/org/signup/signup.route.js:5:58)
apis_1      |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

this is the code

```
        if (!user) {
          return h.response({
            message: "User does not exist",
          });
        } else if (!upassword) {
          return h.response({
            message: "Your Password is incorrect",
          });
        } else {
          let token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "1h",
          });
          if (!token) {
            console.log("token not found");
          }
          return h.response({
            message: "you have successfully logged in",
            token: `${token}`,
          });
        }
```

I am trying to get jwt token to access other routes,
I am working in node typescript Hapi and docker

Answer to Phil's Question,
User is schema or model for sql database
and findOne I am not sure as well because this code was already built and the framework i am using is Hapi.js

```
 import { ServerRoute } from "@hapi/hapi";
import Joi, { options } from "joi";
import { ISignup, IsLogin } from "./signup.types";
import firebase from "firebase-admin";
import { User } from "../../user/user.model";
import { Org } from "../org.model";
```

Comment: if i remove the token var it works fine, So the error is only in the part of jwt

Comment: It's telling you that `user` (the _payload_) is not a plain object. So the question is, where does `user` come from?

Comment: Code goes in your question, not the comments. Please [edit] it. Also, what framework are you using? What is `User` and where does the `findOne()` method come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsonwebtoken [expects the first argument](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/sign.js#L40) to be a [plain object](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/is-plain-object/).

If it is a database document, deconstruct the required data into a plain object.

```
let token = jwt.sign({ name: user.name }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
   expiresIn: "1h",
});
```

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))` might also work to convert the whole object.

Comment: Depending on what produces `user` value, there might be a _flatten_ method or similar (I'm guessing Sequelize)

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that You're sending the user data directly to jwt.sign() function while it accepts the first parameter as a plain object plus you should generate token base on Id as it will always be unique for every user. So your code should be like this

```
if (!user) {
          return h.response({
            message: "User does not exist",
          });
        } else if (!upassword) {
          return h.response({
            message: "Your Password is incorrect",
          });
        } else {
          const payload = {userId : user.id}
          let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: "1h",
          });
          if (!token) {
            console.log("token not found");
          }
          return h.response({
            message: "you have successfully logged in",
            token: `${token}`,
          });
        }
```